# Dividing triple integral to evaluate the integrals in closed-form

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following triple integral

$$\int_{y_1=0}^{\infty}\int_{y_2=0}^{\infty}\int_{x_2=0}^{zy_2}\exp\left(-\min\left[x_2,\,y_1(z-\frac{x_2}{y_2})\right]\right)\,dx_2dy_1dy_2$$

I want to divide the integrals into intervals to evaluate it. What I did was that I divided the inner most integral into two interval as following

$$\int_{x_2=0}^{\frac{z\,y_1y_2}{y_1+y_2}}\exp\left(-x_2\right)\,dx_2 + \int_{x_2=\frac{z\,y_1y_2}{y_1+y_2}}^{zy_2}\exp\left(-y_1(z-\frac{x_2}{y_2})\right)\,dx_2$$

Although this allows us to evaluate the integral over $x_2$ easily, the integration over $y_1$ and $y_2$ will be harder.

My actual problem is a little more complicated, and this question is used to capture the essence of the problem. Thus, I am not looking for a solution for the integrals as they are, but rather I need a method where I can divide all the integrals (not just the inner most one) into intervals that makes the evaluation of all integrals much simpler. Is this feasible?

EDIT: My actual problem is the following

$$\int_{y_1=0}^{\infty}\int_{y_2=0}^{\infty}\int_{x_2=0}^{zy_2}\exp\left(-\min\left[x_2,\,y_1(z-\frac{x_2}{y_2})\right]\right)e^{-y_1}\,e^{-y_2}\,dx_2dy_1dy_2$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I am not familiar with it. I just read about it though, and I am not sure what you are implying. If you are talking about why I didn't post my original problem, it is because I think it won't change anything in the approach. But here it is in case you are wondering and it is important to the solution $$\int_{y_1=0}^{\infty}\int_{y_2=0}^{\infty}\int_{x_2=0}^{zy_2}\exp\left(-\min\left[x_2,\,y_1(z-\frac{x_2}{y_2})\right]\right)e^{-y_1}\,e^{-y_2}\,dx_2dy_1dy_2$$ I hope this provides enough information.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply anything; my apologies. It's not uncommon for people on this site to have burrowed their way into a problem and ask for help on a tiny piece of it that ultimately doesn't have much to do with their end goal. When you mentioned "[your] actual problem," I wondered if that was what had happened here, but I see now that that's not the case. Within reason, more detail and context never hurt!

Comment: I admit I don't know how to solve your problem, but hopefully what you've provided is enough that someone more knowledgeable than me can help you with it!